# Are there any differences between Gnu sed's "i text" and "i\ ...." commands?

Tags: sed

Below is an excerpt from Gnu sed's documentation at https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

```
i text
insert text before a line. This is a GNU extension to the
standard i command - see below for details.

i\
text
Immediately output the lines of text which follow this command.
```

The wording of these two syntaxes is quite different. In the past, I thought they have the exact same behavior and it's just the syntax is different. I did a bunch of experiment and all tests give the same result. I want to confirm, are there any differences between these two syntaxes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: They work the same, only the syntax is different. Including the range GNU extension (eg. `3,4ifoo`) works with both syntaxes. You can have a look at the [source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=sed.git;a=blob;f=sed/compile.c;h=7081fc966e2295a5da17b1efea27e827dd568271;hb=a9cb52bcf39f0ee307301ac73c11acb24372b9d8#l1111),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `i text` syntax is extension to the POSIX standard syntax for the `i` command in `sed`, provided as a convenience (as often is the case with GNU extension).

The standard `i` command [looks like](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/sed.html)

```
i\
text
```

and POSIX documents this tersely with

> Write text to standard output.

GNU `sed` provides the same syntactical convenience for the `a` and `c` commands as it does for `i`.  The following is from the `info sed` documentation regarding the `a` command (GNU `sed` version 4.2.2):

> As a GNU extension, if between the `a` and the newline there is
>    other than a whitespace-`\` sequence, then the text of this line,
>    starting at the first non-whitespace character after the `a`, is
>    taken as the first line of the TEXT block.  (This enables a
>    simplification in scripting a one-line add.)  This extension also
>    works with the `i` and `c` commands.

This implies that the two commands

```
i text
```

and

```
i\
text
```

are identical in GNU `sed`.

Comment: they've [changed the wording](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=sed.git;a=commitdiff;h=801a2c83b2c605d136efd7308e7a6bdae0bec286) (to the one from the OP) in newer versions of the info manual.

Comment: @mosvy I noticed, which is why I included the version I have on my system. The old wording that I quoted was clearer and more precise IMHO.